# why does Splitter return the collection directly In the case of dealing with items of the collection in Spring Integration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

When I read the book "Spring in Action 5" and reached chapter 9 "Integrating Spring",especially in the section "Splitters",the book showed that you could return the collection directly in the Splitter method at the time of separating the collection into items each sent to another Channel for processing.I read it again and again but still couldn't get it,why not separate the collection first and then return each item to another Channel?Can anyone please help me understand it more clearly?Thanks a lot.

the book first said:

> But what if you want to break it down further such that instead of dealing with a List of LineItems,you process each LineItem separately? **All you need to do to split the line-item list into multiple messages, one for each line item, is write a method (not a bean) that’s annotated with @Splitter and returns a collection of LineItems.**

The code in the book shows below:

```
@Splitter(inputChannel="lineItemsChannel",outputChannel="lineItemChannel")
public List<LineItem> lineItemSplitter(List<LineItem> lineItems) {
    return lineItems;
}
```

And the book explains about this code:

> When a message carrying a payload of List arrives in the channel named lineItemsChannel, it passes into the lineItemSplitter() method.**Per the rules of a splitter, the method must return a collection of the items to be split. In this case, you already have a collection of LineItems, so you just return the collection directly.** As a result, each LineItem in the collection is published in a message of its own to the channel named lineItemChannel.(from 9.2.5 Splitters)

But I think the "lineItemSplitter" Splitter method should return each item to the outputChannel "lineItemChannel" for processing one by one(also I couldn't imagine how to write this code under my expression,hope you understand what I have thought).

Answer (score 0):

The actual splitting (sending to the output channel) is done by the framework. Your splitter code returns the collection and the framework emits each split as a discrete message.

In later versions (since the book was written), you can now also return an `Iterator` or `Iterable`. This was useful, for example, in the `FileSplitter` because it avoids loading the entire file into memory.